# Can i use Google App Engine as a replacement for Google Apps to send email from php-driven webapp?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, email, google-apps

Righty, I'll use bullets to make this as clear as possible!

- My application lives on my server (and doesn't use G.A.E)
- Currently I use Google Apps (paid) as my mail server in PHP, it's great but...
- It's limited to ~2000 emails per day, i need to send more in the forthcoming version of my web app.

.

1. Can i use GAE's just for emailing via their remote api?
2. Can i view the sent/received email in Gmail like i can with Google Apps?
3. Am i totally barking up the wrong tree?!

Comment: Isn't all your questions by any chance already documented ?

Comment: Hi HamZa, I've a had a look and it looks like you can use the remote api without anything else. I'm more concerned that this might just be a bad idea in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can [send emails from GAE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/mail/), even in PHP. You need a valid Gmail or Google Apps account to use as sender address.

Things to note:

- The cost of one email is $0.0001.
- The size of sent/received emails add to the bandwidth cost.
- There are [quotas](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Mail), varying for free apps and billable apps. Free
  app limit is 100/day, billable app quota is 20,000/day. (You need to
  pay the first bill in order to go beyond free quota limit, even if
  you already enabled billing). You need to have premier account to go
  beyond 20,000/day limit (they might approve it without premier
  account if you ask them.
- There are [technical limits](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/mail/#Quotas_and_Limits).
- No, emails sent from GAE do not show up in senders outbox.

**Update:** GAE can send emails and is pretty good at that. But it's not a generic SMTP server, so it's not a drop-in replacement for services like mailgun. Also it does not do "value-added" mail services, like maillist management, tracking, etc.. This is all doable but you have to code it yourself.

Comment: Do you have any opinions on how it would compare to something like http://www.mailgun.com/ ? Cheers!

Comment: GAE seems to be cheaper. Also GAE is a generic application platform, you can program it to perform many tasks not only send emails. For example you can receive email responses and do some action based on that, etc.. OTOH it requires you to write code, so it's not out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I just found this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/pgoV5ShOmYs/uQorsITU44gJ, do you agree with Bryce's comments?

Comment: Yes, I agree with sending address/domain limits. But this is an issue with all mail sending platforms - you will want to have DKIM and SPF fields set (=signed email) in order for your email to not go into spam anyway. This basically prevents you from sending emails in the name of random users.